# Firebase.once() makes performance slower?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening Everyone , my question here is that Firebase.once(), and also i have tried Firebase.on(); makes of low performance.. So basically im in this stage where user can bookmark a topic.. And here are my minimal code showing that.

**Minimal HTML:**

```
<span ng-if="currentAuthGet!=null;">        
            <span class="bookmark_topic_button">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                            Bookmark
                        </md-tooltip>
                        <span ng-if="bookMarkToggleTopic" ng-click="bookmarkClickOutlineTopic();">
                            <ng-md-icon icon="bookmark_outline" style="fill: #ff6400;" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-if="!bookMarkToggleTopic" ng-click="bookmarkClickNonOutlineTopic();">
                             <ng-md-icon icon="bookmark" style="fill: #009688;" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                        </span>
                </md-button>
            </span>
        </span>
```

**Minimal JS** :

```
 //BookMark
           //Ng-if
             //Toggle
                $scope.bookMarkToggleTopic = true;
           //Ng-Click    
             $scope.bookmarkClickOutlineTopic = function() {
                 refService.ref().child("Topics").once("value", function(snapshotBookMarkOutlineTopic){
                     snapshotBookMarkOutlineTopic.forEach(function(evenChildBook){
                          var bookkey = evenChildBook.key();
                          var bookchildData = evenChildBook.val();
                          if(bookchildData.Postnum == $stateParams.POST){
                              refService.ref().child("Topics").child(bookchildData.pushKey).child("Bookmarks").child($scope.currentAuthGet.uid).update({
                                 Bookmark : true  
                              })
                          }
                     })
                 })
               $scope.bookMarkToggleTopic = false;
             }
             $scope.bookmarkClickNonOutlineTopic = function() {
                 refService.ref().child("Topics").once("value", function(snapshotBookMarkOutlineTopic){
                     snapshotBookMarkOutlineTopic.forEach(function(evenChildBook){
                          var bookkey = evenChildBook.key();
                          var bookchildData = evenChildBook.val();
                          if(bookchildData.Postnum == $stateParams.POST){
                              refService.ref().child("Topics").child(bookchildData.pushKey).child("Bookmarks").child($scope.currentAuthGet.uid).update({
                                 Bookmark : false  
                              })
                          }
                     })
                 })
                $scope.bookMarkToggleTopic = true;
             }
```

So as soon as the user clicks the Book Mark Button two things happen. First, the bookmark non-outline icon goes to the right? And the out-line icon goes to the left??? Note that this only happenes when i add that firebase code which i need for it to become dynamic. This is an image representing that issue:

[image]

And also, the browser becomes incredibly slow! I mean, verrrryyy slow. I dont know why this is happening, if you guys want more code i would happily provide it, help would be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT

This is a very big hint i guess? There is this HUGGGEEEEE Error List Image(Since i cant copy that huge error duh):

[image]